# When using Json file in angular it throws 404 error?

Tags: json, angular, get, http-status-code-404, httpclient

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Players } from './players'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-json-with-search',
  templateUrl: './json-with-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./json-with-search.component.scss']
})
export class JsonWithSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  player: Players[];
  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('/sample.json').subscribe((result)=> {
      //this.player = result;
      console.log(result)
    }, (error)=> {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

}
```

this is my code

i tried to get data from local json file but it returns 404 error

can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: make sure your json file is in the `assets` folder and then request it by `./assets/sample.json`

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its works fine.